# PHP MYSQL How to check if record already exists when UPDATING?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, exists

For my employee's table, an e-mail is a unique field. When I insert a new employee, I check on the existance of the email. If it already exists, you get an error message:

```
    $selectquery ="SELECT * FROM employee WHERE empemail='$empemail'";
    $selectresult=mysql_query($selectquery) or die("query fout " . mysql_error() );
    if(mysql_num_rows($selectresult)==1)
    {
        $errormsgnewemployee = '<p id=notification>The email you entered already exists.</p>';
    }
```

But how to do it when UPDATING a field? Because if I update an employees data (without changing his mail), it will not let me, because the email already exists. All I can think of it is to UPDATE first, check then if there are 2 records, if there are 2, update it back as it was before.

Is this a good approach or is there a better solution?

*EDIT*

My own solution is to UPDATE the table having a `unique index` on the table and using the query error:

```
    if (mysql_error())
            {
                $errormsgnewemployee = '<p id=notification>Update failed. Please check if the email you entered already exists.</p>';
            }
```

Because, why else would the user have error if it's not for the only unique field? In all other cases the update would succeed.

Comment: Why don't you pass a parameter in your form, whether to say `$action = UPDATE` or `INSERT` ?

Comment: that not the problem Touki, it's about how to write a check on the UPDATE matter, not returning a database error but my own text. I'm trying the solution with catching the error number, looking up syntax etc.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the same solution, you just need to "fetch this email address, but not mine" to check if there are any **other** users using it.

Eg. Before the update, do something like this:

`SELECT 1 FROM employee WHERE empemail = '$empemail' AND id != '$myid';`

Should only return rows where the email belongs to someone else.

On a side note, there are potential security issues with interpolating variables into SQL queries like that - you shouldn't do it. And the mysql_* functions are being deprecated should be replaced with PDO or mysqli alternatives.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE ...` sql construction. Take a deeper look at [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

So your query could be the following:

```
INSERT INTO employee (email, first_name, last_name, ...) 
VALUES ('employee_email@example.com', 'nik', 'smtih', ...) 
ON DUPLICATE UPDATE 
    first_name = 'nik', 
    last_name = 'smith', 
    ...
```

Pay attention that `INSERT` part of this query will fail due to `UNIQUE KEY` constraint, that is why the second part of the query, `ON DUPLICATE UPDATE`, will be executed and the data will be updated instead of inserting.

Comment: Thanks, this really is usefull. But how could I now let the user know when it's updated successfully and when it's updated except for the email, for example